# Hibernate Hql Query Selecting a property of inner object

Tags: hibernate, hql

here is the situation : I have a Class A that contains an Object B, what i want to do is to write a Select query witch extracts the A object with only one property of B witch is loaded

Example :

```
Class A {
   private B b;
}


Class B {
  private String s1;
  private Strung s2;
  private String s3;
```

}

I want to extract the A object, with only the B.s1 wich is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
select
  a,
  b.s1
from A a join a.B b
```

This loads and initializes instances of `A`. If `B` is lazy loaded, it doesn't load anything about `B`, except of the explicitly loaded s1. If it is not lazy loaded, you probably should only load the ids, if at all.

```
select
  a.id,
  b.s1
from A a join a.B b
```